# Python pandas groupby get list in the cell (excel)

Tags: python, excel, pandas

So I'm very new with pandas excel in python
here's what I'm trying to achieve

[data before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7TGG.png)

[what I'm trying to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vg3Vr.png)

I haven't found specific ways to do this with groupby
pls help

Comment: Please note that [ask] specifically says *not* to use screenshots of code/data/errors.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `groupby` then `agg`

```py
df['c'] = df['c'].astype(str)

out = df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['c'].agg(','.join).reset_index()
```

```
print(out)

   a  b    c
0  1  2  3,4
1  1  3    5
2  2  2  3,4
3  2  3    5
4  5  6    7
```

Comment: omg just gonna try it out